# valid argument forms to deduce the conclusion from the premises, please explain to me , to understand this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$p \rightarrow q \\
r \lor s \\
\lnot s \rightarrow \lnot t \\
\lnot q \lor s \\
\lnot s \\
\lnot p \land r \rightarrow u \\
w \lor t$$

Is this a valid argument to deduce the conclusion from the premises?
I want to understand the argument above. Can you please explain it to me with reasons for each step? Thank you.

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but could you please clarify your question? What are the premises and what is the conclusion? Which statements are part of the development?

Answer (score 1):

1 p→q
2 r∨s
3 ¬s→¬t
4 ¬q∨s
5 ¬s
6 ¬p∧r→u
7 w∨t
4,5 give not q
not q, 1 give not p
2,5 give r
not p, r, 6 give u
3,5 give not t
not t, 7 give w
ergo u and w

Comment: what rules of inference  every step?

Comment: Learn something.  You make the rules.